# Android mobclix ad pops up without clicking on it

Tags: android, mobclix

So I'm using the latest mobclix library to display ads on my app. Something new that has started happening is that sometimes when initializing the ad bar I get pop-ups (from vdopia) without clicking on the bar. I'm thinking that this is just the nature of some of the ads because no events fire to make me think the ad bar is mistakenly believing it was clicked. Can anyone confirm- do you get pop-ups that take over the screen occasionally when using mobclix?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newest version includes interstitial ads. In the sdk there is a setting to allow autoplay, i think its setAllowAutoplay, if that is set to true then the ads will automatically play. I'm not sure of the default settings.

Comment: Thanks a lot- I'm not sure if that is the ultimate fix but I haven't seen the interstitials since making that adjustment.